# How can I inject bundle source before a code in body using HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using Google map api with webpack, To generate a google map, It's supposed to load bundle file before load API js file. but HtmlWebpackPlugin places bundle file at the bottom of body element. How can I load bundle before the bundle file? This is my `webpack.config.js` below.

```
const webpack = require('webpack'); var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server',"./public/entry.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "bundle-[hash].js",
        publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '/')
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        inline: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
            { test: /\.jade$/, loader: "pug-loader"}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ 
            template: './views/index.jade',
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    } };
```

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIfcx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ 
    template: './views/index.jade',
    inject: 'body'
})
```

> inject: (`true` | `'head'` | `'body'` | `false`)
>   Inject all assets into the given template or templateContent - When passing true or 'body' all javascript resources will be placed at the bottom of the body element. 'head' will place the scripts in the head element.

See [Configuration docs](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#configuration) for more details.